# Windows 10 is Activated Using Organization's Activation Service Instead of Digital License

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, windows-activation, microsoft-account

Windows 10 Pro came with my machine and it used to say *"Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft account."*

***UPDATE:*** Correcting the above information. My PC was built by the shop from parts. I assume they installed Windows 10 Pro on it, but what I am not sure about is how I got a Digital Certificate in the first place and how it got tied to my Microsoft account as it's been so long.

I recently had an SSD installed at a computer shop, had them make it my primary drive, and had them install Windows 10 Pro on it.

When I got home, I logged into my Microsoft account to sync my Windows activation with Microsoft.

However, when I checked my Activation status, it now says *"Windows is activated using your organization's activation service."*

This came as a surprise as I don't belong to any organization and it's a home computer.

My Microsoft account is already signed in to the PC and is an Administrator, but it doesn't seem to be linking the license that I assume I still have to my PC.

However, when I check my account info on *account.microsoft.com*, I do see my PC under Devices and it says that no issues are found.

Unfortunately, I can't open the Activation Troubleshooter nor add a Microsoft account in the Activation settings as Windows 10 is already activated.

My questions are:

1. Should I be worried that my license will eventually expire? There doesn't seem to be any way to tell how long it will remain valid.

   ***UPDATE:*** You can check how long your license will last by running `slmgr /xpr` in the command prompt.
2. Is there a way to force Windows to link to the digital license that it used to say I have on my Microsoft account?

   Or perhaps I need to contact someone at Microsoft to have them turn my license into a digital one?

I can't imagine moving Windows from an HDD to an SSD to be a super significant hardware change as it's a very common scenario and the motherboard and other parts were left untouched.

Comment: I'd use a different shop next time. I'm guessing that they used a VLK key [rather stupidly, as they didn't need **any** key at all] rather than your own digital entitlement. Either have a look at this, or take it back & make them do it properly - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-is-activated-using-your-organizations/a4c61889-b0b1-4c68-ba9f-fa64f974b73a

Comment: The shop installed the incorrect edition of Windows 10.  You will want the correct edition (same edition you had before) yourself.  **Windows licenses do not expire.**  Microsoft cannot help you with a problem like this, your issue is one created by the shop, they have no record of your actual license key so they wouldn't be able to provide it to you.  Yes; I am speaking of a support agent not having records of your license key.  They can only help you activate your installation, but as you point out, it's already activated.

Comment: @Ramhound The Windows version is the same (Windows 10 Pro). I will edit the OP to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases) is the only tool I know that detects the correct key.   Which key does it detect? Is it the incorrect key the shop provided?

Comment: @Ramhound I opened the app. What specific field do you want me to check?

Comment: [I am asking if the product key you were using matches your OEM key or is a different key.](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12848924/9773837/1cf16e00-5745-11e5-95b2-853893a4ef17.PNG);

Comment: @Ramhound For "OEM key," it says "OEM key not present in firmware."

Comment: @FloatingSunfish - Was this hardware prebuilt by an OEM or did you build it yourself

Comment: @Ramhound I had the same shop build it over a year ago from various parts. Although now that you mention it, OEM means it came bundled with the hardware. Perhaps they did install Windows 10 themselves (we asked them not to do anything before we got there, but perhaps they forgot, so when we got there, Windows was already running). One thing I'm not sure about is how I would have a Digital License linked to my MS account.

Comment: @FloatingSunfish - You have left vital information out of your question.  If you didn’t link your user profile to a Microsoft Account then you wouldn’t have a digital entitlement.  Furthermore, if they built it and provide you a legal copy of Windows 10, you should have been provided a the license with a COA sticker.  It sounds like during the upgrade they didn’t use your original key.  The shop must resolve the issue you describe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128009/discussion-between-floating-sunfish-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I recently had an SSD installed at a computer shop, had them make it
> my primary drive, and had them install Windows 10 on it.

Contact the shop, and have them change the Windows Key to your original license.

Your own key should have been used and will work. You can always change a disk on a Windows 10 computer.  I have done this myself.

The shop is responsible for this and should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered that I should contact the shop to resolve this issue as it is indeed their responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the activation done by the shop, to install your own:

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter the following command: `slmgr /upk`
- Wait for the message "Uninstalled product key successfully"
- Windows will become deactivated
- Run *Settings > Update & Security > Activation*
- Verify that Activation is "Windows is not activated".
- Select "Add an account"
- Enter your Microsoft account and password and select "Sign in"
- If successful, on the Activation page you’ll see
  "Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft account".

Comment: `slmgr /upk` did remove the key on my machine. However, when I click Troubleshoot, it just reuses the organization key instead of letting me add a Microsoft account as described in the URL below. Any advice on how to remove the key so Troubleshoot won't find it? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reactivating-windows-10-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665

Comment: Update: I tried `slmgr /upk`, `slmgr /cpky`, `slmgr /rearm`, and then restarted my PC, but when I clicked the Activation troubleshooter, it still used the organization key.

Comment: Unless you replace the key all you have done is reactivate the incorrect key. All you should have done is,* slmgr /upk*, restart and made sure your local account was linked to the correct Microsoft Account (unnecessary step but makes it easier)